# How to use inclusterconfig for multiple clusters

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-go-client

How can we use inclusterconfig for multiple clusters?

I tried below code for one cluster

```
rest.InclusterConfig
```

Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to use in cluster config to connect to a cluster which is not the current cluster where the pod is deployed because client-go uses the service account token (valid for the current cluster) mounted inside the pod at the `/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount` path when the `rest.InClusterConfig()` is used.